# Firefox window.opener issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, new-operator, tabs, window.opener

"window.opener" works fine in both IE and Firefox as long as 'Open in New Tab' is used from the right-click menu; Error console says "window.opener" is null. Is there any other way the opener can be accessed?

Edit:
Error console says "window.opener" is null only when "Open in New Tab" is clicked. For all other cases, there is no such error. Hence, what i would like to know is if an alternate other than "window.opener" exists.

Answer (score 2):

`window.opener` only works if the window (or tab, if it was diverted into a tab) was opened with `window.open` or via a `target` attribute or similar. In particular, the UI never sets the opener of a window.

Answer (score -5):

it's **window.open()** IIRC

Comment: That opens a new window, it doesn't get a reference to the window object for the window that opened the current window.