# window.opener is null in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a page which opens the popup as

```
openWindow(top, 'prcsTypeSelectionPopup?event=prcsTypeSelection', 'lovWindow', {width:750, height:550}, true, 'dialog', pathCallBack);
```

and the popup has the following code

```
function returnSelect()
{
    window.document.forms[0].choice_processType.value ;
    window.opener.document.forms[0].pevent.value = 'getprocessName';
    window.opener.document.forms[0].processName.value='';
    for (var i=0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++)
   {
   if (document.forms[0].elements[i].checked)
      {
      window.opener.document.forms[0].processName.value=document.forms[0].elements[i].value;
      break;
      }
   }
   if(window.opener.document.forms[0].processName.value=='')    {
        window.opener.document.forms[0].lovProcessType.value = '';
        window.opener.document.forms[0].pevent.value = '';
   }
    window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();
    closeConn();
}

function closeConn()
{
         self.close();
}
```

But when the page is loaded in firefox, am getting the error as 
window.opener is null at the 2nd line of returnselect() function

```
function returnSelect()
    {
        window.document.forms[0].choice_processType.value ;
        --> window.opener.document.forms[0].pevent.value = 'getprocessName';
```

Any idea how to overcome this

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944066/firefox-window-opener-issue

Comment: @sergzach: the page has no direct answer... can u pls help in my case

Comment: Please let me know if my answer is not useful. It's an only idea, I do not know 100% decision.

Comment: Try to use the standart window.open function instead of openWindow. Is there the same error? Or give the source code of openWindow.

Comment: -> window.open( 'prcsTypeSelectionPopup?event=prcsTypeSelection', 'lovWindow' );

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Comment: I changed my answer. Please see.

Comment: Give me an implementation of openWindow please. It's a blackbox.

Comment: I add information about root path in my answer. See.

Comment: If the problem is still actual you can paste your code to jsfiddle.net and publish a link, let's see together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works only for "parent.window.opener" and not for "window.opener"

Thanks Sergzach for your time

Answer (score 11):

**You open a window from another domain/subdomain. In this case you don't have access to parent window that opened the target window because security permissions don't allow that.**

- For example, if you open a page of **site2.com** from a page of **site1.com** the target window has it's opener *null*.
- If you open a page of **site2.site.com** from a page of **site1.site.com** — it's also no access because these are two different sites.
- But if you a page of **site.com** page from page of **site.com** or page of **subdomain.site.com** from page of **site.com** — you have the access because security permissions allow that.

Note: maybe 'prcsTypeSelectionPopup?event=prcsTypeSelection' is incorrect. Change it to root correct path without domain, an example:

/prcsTypeSelectionPopup?event=prcsTypeSelection

Comment: am able to open the popup and when i am clicking the button in child window to send some data to parent window, that time only am getting the error "window.opener is null" and the child window is not closing

Comment: @siva So, don't you have the problem in another places? Only in button click handler?

Comment: @siva I don't see a body of openWindow(), it's difficult to help further.

Answer (score -1):

Try do disable the next Firefox extention:
Tabbrowser Extensions (TBE).

It seems that there is the mentioned problem when using it .

Comment: @siva The extention, as I know, is not installed with firefox. But some people use it.

Comment: i checked with IE too.. there also its not working and getting "window.opener is null" error message

Comment: @siva There is completely different problem. I thought that you talked about Firefox only.

Comment: @siva I think there are wrong options for openWindow. See my comments above, please.

Comment: i changed openwindow to window.open('prcsTypeSelectionPopup?event=prcsTypeSelection', 'lovWindow', 'width=750,height=550); and still the issue is not resolved.... any ideas