# window.opener doesn't work in firefox and chrome but in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, window.open, window.opener

I have a problem with the window.opener function (JS):

I created 3 simple pages to simulate my problem:

test.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="window.open('first_page_in_popup.php', 'Popup', 'width=470,height=500');">    
        <input type="text" id="content" name="content" >
    </body>
</html>
```

first_page_in_popup.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            window.opener.document.getElementById('content').value= "Test from first page in popup";
            window.open('second_page_in_popup.php', 'Popup');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

second_page_in_popup.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            window.opener.document.getElementById('content').value= "Test from second page in popup";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:
In IE, the input field has the content "Test from second page in popup".
In Chrome and Firefox, the content is : "Test from first page in popup".

The Error Message:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Comment: This might be a security restriction. I experienced that Chrome refused to let the popup get/set values of the opener. Did you try making a function in the main window that you call from the popup?

Comment: works great here in Firefox, i can do this from my popup and replace the content: window.opener.document.getElementById('maincontent').innerHTML = "test";
Could you create a fiddle to recreate your issue?

Comment: if i rename the second popup to "Popup2" and change the code from the secondpage to:
window.opener.opener.document.getElementById('content').value= "Test from second page in popup";
it works. But now i have to popups open ... and i want only one window.

Answer (score 2):

try `parent.window.opener` instead of `window.opener`

**Source:** [window.opener is null in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902677/window-opener-is-null-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the code of page "first_page_in_popup.php" to:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            window.opener.document.getElementById('content').value= "Test from first page in popup";
            window.location.href = 'second_page_in_popup.php';

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> First Page </p> 
        <input type="text" id="first" name="first">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(...) is null
```

that means content in window.opener.document.getElementById is null or undefined 
please try to define

```
content in second php as defined in first php
```

hope this will work.